# Configure Eclipse to work with Opensplice DDS

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, data-distribution-service, opensplice

To get Eclipse working with DDS, you have to add these configurations in Project properties:

PROJECT→PROPERTIES→C/C++ GENERAL→PATHS AND SYMBOLS→INCLUDES→GNU C++

```
/yourddspath/include/sys
/yourddspath/include/dcps/C++/SACPP
/PROJECTNAME/idl/generated (added like path of your project).
```

PROJECT→PROPERTIES→C/C++ GENERAL→PATHS AND SYMBOLS→Library Paths ou PROJECT→PROPERTIES→C/C++ Build→Settings→Cross G++ Linker→Libraries→Library search path (-L)→+

```
/yourddspath/lib
```

PROJECT→PROPERTIES→C/C++ Build→Settings→Cross G++ Linker→Libraries→Libraries (-l)→+

```
pthread
ddskernel
dcpssacpp
libbgs_types.a
dl
```

PROJECT→PROPERTIES→C/C++ Build→Environnement→Add ou Edit

```
SPLICE_ORB=DDS_OpenFusion_1_6_1
SPLICE_JDK=jdk
OSPL_HOME=/yourddspath
VORTEX_DIR=/yourddspath/etc
PATH=/yourddspath/bin:$PATH (WARNING,Here $PATH is preexisting PATH environement variable)
CPATH=/yourddspath/include:/yourddspath/include/sys
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/yourddspath/lib
OSPL_URI=file:yourddspath/etc/config/ospl.xml 
OSPL_TMPL_PATH=/yourddspath/etc/idlpp
```

For now, I don't know how to automatically execute prebuild idl generation in generated folder. I just use a makefile and a prebuild terminal command as make idl. If someone can help to prebuild idl generation, let me know!